# Reveal Text from center with CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm kind of new to CSS3 Animations and hope anybody out there could help me realising this.

I'm having a div with text in it. I would like to reveal this div from the center. It looks kind of simple, but until now I didn't find the perfect way to realise it.

Do I need to use

```
.text-div {
    clip-path: inset(top right bottom left);
    animate: revealText 3s;
}

@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(top right bottom left);
  },
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(top right bottom left);
  }
}
```

or would you suggest another way to solve this?

[image: Bild1]
[image: Bild2]]
[image: Bild3]]

Thanks for your help!
Cara

Comment: What kind of animation you want? A fade-in? A type kind of animation? Any movement?

Comment: Sorry, It's hard for me to describe this in English. I want the text to be revealed from the CENTER of the text. Like sliding from the middle without scaling the text. No fading, no type kind.

Comment: @CaraMar check my answer below. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I realised it in the end. It appears to me, that until now, there is no easier way to do this.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ukqv9qa1/)

```
.text-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  clip-path: inset(0px 50% 0px 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 50% 0px 50%);
  animation: revealText 3s;
}
.content {
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 50% 0px 50%);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 50% 0px 50%);
   }
  100% {
     clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
     -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
}
```

Thanks everybody for input!

Answer (score 4):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/y76qu9dy/2/)**

i used : `width:0%` on the animation to hide the text , and added `white-space:nowrap` to initial state of the text so it doesn't go on two separate lines because of the `width:0%` and added `overflow:hidden`

play around with the css i gave you , remove some of the things to see how they work

css :

```
.text-div {
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    animation: revealText 3s;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:45%;
}
.content {
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
    width:0%;

   }
  100% {
    width:100%;

  }
}
```

***EDIT*** you could use `pseudo-elements` like `:before` and `:after` , but this only if you have a background color underneath the text . like in this example `red`

see here : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/y76qu9dy/52/)**

css :

```
.text-div {
color:white;
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
top:45%;
}
.text-div:before {
left:0;
}
.text-div:after {
right:0;
}
.text-div:after,.text-div:before { 
position:absolute;
content:"";
height:100%;
width:50%;
background:red;
animation: revealText 3s;
}

.content {
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
     width:50%
    }
  100% {
     width:0%
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, this is a great idea! Unfortunately the text doesn't stay fixed at the center. It should not move. I realised it with the clip-path, as there is probably no easier way to do it. I was hoping there could be a ready-made css transition for this. But thanks for your help!

Comment: edited my answer with another solution , but it's a bit more css to it