# Use CSS animation to reveal text from center and keep text visible at end

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using code from [Reveal Text from center with CSS Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348202/reveal-text-from-center-with-css-animation) to reveal text from the center. *But* I'd like to keep the text visible after the animation is over. Right now, the text disappears after the animation. I'm new to css animation, so I'm not sure what the right thing to do is.

css:

```
.text-div {
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top:45%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text-div:before {
  left:0;
}
.text-div:after {
  right:0;
}
.text-div:after,.text-div:before { 
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background:black;
  animation: revealText 3s;
}

.content {
  background:black;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
     width:50%
    }
  100% {
     width:0%
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="text-div">
  The subculture
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `animation-fill-mode:forwards` to `.text-div:after,.text-div:before` as below,

```
.text-div:after,.text-div:before { 
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background:black;
  animation: revealText 3s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Add this*/
}
```

> The animation-fill-mode CSS property specifies how a CSS animation
>   should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing.

```css
.text-div {
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top:45%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text-div:before {
  left:0;
}
.text-div:after {
  right:0;
}
.text-div:after,.text-div:before { 
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background:black;
  animation: revealText 3s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

.content {
  background:black;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
     width:50%
    }
  100% {
     width:0%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="text-div">
  The subculture
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I'll mark your answer as right in 3 minutes.

Comment: Yes and Welcome : -) to end animation by keeping element visible in end use animation-fill-mode:forwards, do read more about that.